# What is the meaning of `Disallow: /? in a robots.txt file?

Tags: robots.txt

What is the meaning of `Disallow: /? in a robots.txt file?

```
User-agent: *  
Disallow: /?*
```

Comment: The statement means all user-agents are disallowed from accessing URLs that starts with a query string at the root directory. It appears that you didn't bother to search the Internet before asking. [What is a robots.txt file?](https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt)

Comment: @TimR Please help keep the tone of the comments section welcoming for new users. If you believe a question is without merit or shows no research effort, you can vote it down. Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, It means everything that start with question mark in "?" is not allowed to crawl and index. For instance example.com/category/?sort=from1to10 and similar type of URL will be disregarded to crawl. Also these type of query parameter pages can be there on any directory, it will disregard every occurrence.

Comment: @DeepakMathur, you should make it an answer

Answer (score 1):

Within a robots.txt file a `Disallow` rule blocks crawling and `Allow` rules allow crawling. Bots that respect robots.txt files need to compare the path of the current URL with the paths specified in the `Disallow` and `Allow` rules.

The parsing is quite complex and is described in [RFC 9309](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9309#name-the-allow-and-disallow-line). The matching must be done case sensitive, the most specific match must be used if `Allow` rules and `Disallow` rules a equivalent, `Allow` should be used.

In your example URLs with a path starting with "/?" will be excluded from crawling.

What's noteworthy here is that due to the wildcard `Disallow: /?*` and `Disallow: /?` are equivalent, because the path comparison always is a left match.

Here is a table showing the status for some URLs:

| URL | status |
| --- | --- |
| `https://example.com/` | allowed |
| `https://example.com/?` | disallowed |
| `https://example.com/?foo` | disallowed |
| `https://example.com/foo?` | allowed |
| `https://example.com/foo/?` | allowed |

Note: If you want to block all URLs with a query the rule is insufficient and `Disallow: /*?` must be used instead.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, looks like a comprehensive answer +1